# Redirecting duplicated pages in WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

This is where I'm at:

I have a template (page-compare.php) which uses query vars to get 2 ids of other pages and compare their content.

It looks like this:
http://example.com/compare/?card=3432&vs=454

If I pass the ids in reversed order I get a duplicated page as it has the same Ids.

I mean:

http://example.com/compare/?card=3432&vs=454

and

http://example.com/compare/?card=454&vs=3432

are the same.

I want to be able to redirect
http://example.com/compare/?card=454&vs=3432
to
http://example.com/compare/?card=3432&vs=454

So the function should look for the bigger id and put it first.

After that, if possible I would like to redirect it to a more SEO friendly URL such as:
http://example.com/page-with-bigger-id-slug-vs-page-with-smaller-id-slug

I get both of the pages ids either via direct linking to the pages or using $_GET with a form, here is what I have so far in the page but it is not working.

```
    if($card < $vs) {
    function rewrite_switch_ids() {
    global $card;
    global $vs;
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^compare/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
            '/compare/?card=matches[1]&vs=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
    }
    rewrite_switch_ids();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

I really want to do it on the template file if possible.

Thanks (:

EDIT:

I've tried a different approach which currently works although I'm not quite happy about:

```
   <?php if ($cardOld < $vsOld) {
        $url = get_site_url();
        $url = $url . '/compare/?card=' . $card . '&vs=' . $vs;?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect(){
        window.location="<?php echo $url; ?>";
    }
    Redirect();
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

This redirects the user to the correct page using javascript, and for search engines I've passed the final url with the bigger id using canonical.

I don't really like the solution but it's the best I could come up with.

If anyone else can help me fix it in a better way that will be great, thanks!